# can't pass a value that gets from axios (get request) to my state

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

can't pass a value that gets from axios (get request) to my state

Just looking for another thread .someone told me that I must bind "this" first

```
this.sendgetRequest = this.sendgetRequest.bind(this);
```

but in my case I already did

not sure what my mistake

```
class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

            data : [],
            count : 1


        }
        this.sendgetRequest = this.sendgetRequest.bind(this);
    }

    sendgetRequest(){


        axios.get('https://ywc15.ywc.in.th/api/interview')
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
          this.setState({ data: response.data })
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

}
    render() {

        { this.sendgetRequest() }


        return (
            <div>


            </div>

        );
    };
};


export default Home;
```

error came after inspect console

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at home.js:30
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: You shall not do side effects from `render`.

Answer (score 3):

You're losing the `this` binding, use an arrow function in your callback instead.

```
axios.get('https://ywc15.ywc.in.th/api/interview')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    this.setState({ data: response.data })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

By the way if you're only calling this method once, I would recommend moving the entire `sendgetRequest` inside of `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.sendgetRequest();
}
```

and getting rid of it inside `render`.